# Bootstrap Treeview's href property not rendering a link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, treeview

I'm working on a .net core application where I'm using the Bootstrap Treeview. Here is part of the javascript that sets up my tree:

```
       var tree = [
    {
        text: "Assets",
        href: "http://localhost:63690/asset/index",
        nodes: [
        {
            text: "Barcode"
        },
        {
            text: "Importation"
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "Inventory",
        nodes: [
        {
```

and here is my markup in my view:

```
<div id="tree" class="treeview"></div>
```

Based on the information on [this page](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview) I should just be able to put the URL in the href property. But when I run the app, no link or anchor gets rendered and nothing happens when I click on my Assets node. What am I missing?

I also added the following to geenrate the treeview:

```
 $('#tree').treeview({
        data: tree,
        levels: 5,
        backColor: 'white',
        expandIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right",
        collapseIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom",
        showBorder: false
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just get the same problem, and I find the solution in project's document.

> enableLinks
>
> Boolean. Default: false
>
> Whether or not to present node text as a hyperlink. The href value of
>   which must be provided in the data structure on a per node basis.

So you should add `enableLinks: true` to your code like this:

```
 $('#tree').treeview({
    data: tree,
    levels: 5,
    backColor: 'white',
    expandIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right",
    collapseIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom",
    showBorder: false,
    enableLinks: true
});
```